# Which is the eficiently way to sum like excel does?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table like this:

| Proyect Name | Start Date Act. 1 | Duration Act. 1 | Duration Act. 2 | .... | Start Date Act. N | Duration Act. N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2021 | 5 | 3 | ... | ? | 12 |
| .. | ... | ... | 19 | ... | ... | ... |
| Z | 2/4/2020 | 20 | 1 | ... | ? | 30 |

In this Table, i have different proyects (With different paths) with different starts dates and their durations. The path is stored in a dictionary like in this example:

```
path = {'Act. 1' : ['Act. 2'], 'Act. 2': ['Act. 3', 'Act. 4'], 'Act. 3' : ['Act. 4', 'Act. 5'], 'Act. 4': ['Act. 6']}
```

I want to get the end date of the last activity 'N'. The end date is the result of sum the duration of activities to start day. Also, The start day of the next activity is equal to end date of the previous activity (except for the first one, which is given)

This is the code that i use for obtain the dates:

```
for j in df.index:
    df.loc[j,"End Date Act. 1"] = df.loc[j,"Start Date Act. 1"] + pd.to_timedelta(np.ceil(df.loc[j, "Duration Act. 1"]),unit = 'D')

    for i,m in path.items():
        for k in m:
           df.loc[j,"Start Date Act. "+k] = df.loc[j, "End Date Act. "+i]  
           df.loc[j, "End Date Act. "+k]= df.loc[j,"Start Date Act. "+k] + pd.to_timedelta(np.ceil(df.loc[j, "Duration Act. "+k]),unit = 'D')
```

With Pandas, i sum each row for obtain the expected result. It is the most eficiently way to achieve this?

Comment: So it's correct that you may have identical columns? Like "Duration Act. 1", but also for the other acts? And you need to obtain the largest value for a single project/row each time of those identical columns?

Comment: Not it was a mistake (now is correct). 
what I need to obtain is the final end date value of each project with the sum of the durations of the activities from the initial date of each project, taking account the PATH.

Comment: Please explain your interpretation of the path.  If path = {'Act.1 ':['Act.2', 'ACT-3']} does this imply that Act. 1 can only start after ACT.2 and ACT. 3 are completed?

Comment: Then I'm curious about the use of the `ceil` function (it probably doesn't matter too much for an answer though): are there non-integer values for the acts? Since the example table only shows integer values.

Comment: @itprorh66 If path = {'Act.1 ':['Act.2', 'Act. 3']}  implies that Act.1 implies that implies that to be executed activities 2 and 3, activity 1 must have been completed.

Comment: @9769953, yeah the type numbers are float

Comment: So the keys of the nested dicts are the requirements for "using" the elements of the value list? It may makes sense for a human, but for a computer (program), the inverse might have been easier. Because now, for a single key (say, "act 5"), one has to check each (nested) dict to see if "act 5" is an element of the value list, and then recursively proceed with those keys. Just thinking out loud, but it does make things harder.

Comment: Also, since Activity 1 is dependent on other activities, 'Start Date Act. 1' is in reality the Project Start Date, or can the project start prior to starting ac 1?

Comment: @9769953 yeah, the keys are the requirements, maybe the inverse could be easiest.

Comment: @itprorh66 Start Date Act. 1  = Project Start Date

Comment: When you state you want the end date of the last activity, do you mean the end date of the activity with the highest numerical index or the end date of the last activity associated with project completion?

Comment: @itprorh66 the end date of the last activity associated with project completion